# Request for higher concurrency for Speech-to-text

Tags: azure-cognitive-services, microsoft-speech-api, microsoft-speech-platform

I am a developer at Across Cultures - we provide online EAL (English as an Additional Language) support for learners in schools.

I've been looking at your Speech Services API and have something working for our requirements, however we will need support for more than 20 concurrent connections to the API - currently we are experiencing as much as 100+ concurrent users.

Can you tell me if it is possible to increase the concurrent connections, how it affects price, and if it can auto-scale or do we need to specify the number in advance?

Thanks,

Simon

Answer (score 0):

The faq page: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cognitive-services/speech-service/faq-stt

tells you about the information we need to increase concurrency. Please don't post this information publicly (especially subscription keys etc).

There is no additional cost to increase concurrency. The concurrency defines the upper limit. The service scales dynamically up to that limit.

thx
Wolfgang